# jQuery <tag> sorting by different options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

For example I have got this structure:

```
<a href='#' id='by_id'>Sort by id</a>
<a href='#' id='by_author'>Sort by author</a>
<a href='#' id='by_title'>Sort by title</a>
<div id="my_list">
  <div data-id='1' data-author='Pushkin'>Fairy Tale</div>
  <div data-id='3' data-author='Tolstoy'>Anna Karenina</div>
  <div data-id='2' data-author='Doyl'>Fairy Tale</div>
  <div data-id='5' data-author='Tarantino'>Kill Bill</div>
  <div data-id='9' data-author='Pushkin'>Fairy Tale</div> 
</div>
```

Now I want to sort my divs by title, id or author via clicking on my cool links.

Is there a plugin for this job or it easy to realize without any external libraries?

Comment: Well, if it's a list, UL/LI would be more appropriate (and more readable)...

Comment: Yes, but it is very simple look. Divs can consist images and some more data. I don't think that it is a common list. Anyway it doesn't change anything, if it will be wrapped as a list

Comment: The content model for LI elements and DIV elements is the same (Flow content). The UL element represents a list of items, and what you have there is a list of items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lightweight, simple. Try this :)

```
$('#sortables').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    var by = $(this).attr('id').match(/^by_(.*)/i);
    if (by)
    {
      mySort.sort(by[1]);
    }
});

var mySort = {

  sortables: {
    'title': {
      method: 'text',
      type: 'alpha'
    },
    'author': {
      method: 'attr',
      val: 'data-author',
      type: 'alpha'
    },
    'id': {
      method: 'attr',
      val: 'data-id',
      type: 'numeric'
    }
  },

  sort: function(sortBy)
  {
    if (!mySort.sortables[sortBy]) return;
    var sortedElements = [];
    var sortVal;

    var sort = mySort.sortables[sortBy];

    $('#my_list > div').each(function() {

      sortVal = $(this)[sort.method](sort.val || null);
      sortedElements.push([this, sortVal]);
    });

    // ">" sorts in ascending order, "<" will sort in descending order.
    sortedElements.sort(function(a, b) {
        var result;
        return (sort.type == 'numeric') ?
            a[1] - b[1] :
            a[1] > b[1];
    });

    // Create a new div to replace the old one with
    var $newDiv = $('<div id="my_list">');

    $(sortedElements).each(function() {
        $newDiv.append(this[0]);
    });

    $('#my_list').replaceWith($newDiv);

  }
};
```

Working **fiddle** here: http://jsfiddle.net/fHTmQ/3

Comment: @Gary Could you make a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Obviously it's hard to see the changes for author and id as only the title is displayed, but if you look at the HTML you'll see they are sorted in ascending order. Very elegant and simple. :)

Comment: works fine! Hope you'll wrap it as a plugin ;) to be more universal. Thanx for help!

Comment: Here is little bug: it sorts by first character, so 5 going after 33

Comment: Ah. For numeric sorting you'll need to use `return a[1] - b[1]` in the `.sort()` function. I've updated fiddle and code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use datagrid plugin,

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5

Comment: Nono! It is too big. Here could be something lightweight and simple.

Comment: @floor , ok then lets me search for some more light weight , otherwise you can write customized one by yourself by repopulating html by making acall to ajax again....